# Tokyo ravens volume 14 english

Tags: tokyo-ravens

Is there a english translation of  light novel volume 14 of tokyo ravens?

Answer (score 2):

As of 23/03/2018 there is no official translation of *Tokyo Ravens*'s Light Novel.

Looking on [Manga Update's entry](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=106672) under Licensed (in English) it lists **No** and on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Ravens) and [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=15957) there is no associated English publishers.

Anything outside of this is an unofficial translation and for the purpose of this site, not supported